# Ruby on Rails workaround for the mySQL max int: 2147483647?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, numbers

I'm trying to use this number:

```
294670251400
```

This number will be an attribute in a model that is keeping counter tabs on membership cards. The membership cards have three four digit vanity sets.

But when I update_attribute to contain this, the number is reset to mySQL's max int :

```
2147483647
```

Anyone have a workaround to this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your migration, you can specify the integer as such:

```
  t.integer :really_big_number, :limit => 8
```

Here's a useful [blog post](http://ariejan.net/2009/08/20/once-and-for-all-rails-migrations-integer-limit-option/) about it.

Answer (score 3):

Are you performing mathematical operations within the database? Can you just store it as a string? or a BIGINT?

Comment: What's a BIGINT? Sounds fun. I can't store it as a string, because I need to perform incrementation on it.

Comment: MySQL Numeric Types: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html

Comment: Assuming you do the incrementing in ruby code, you could definitely store it as a string. Incrementing would then just be convert to float or integer, add 1, convert to string again. Or use BIGINT :)

Comment: I'm assuming that keep it a string would enhance server performance?

Comment: I can't think of a reason why -- BIGINT is 8 bytes, while VARCHAR(n) is n+1 bytes.